# No image is displaying

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have placed a ascx file and javascript .It will display a textbox with image but it is not showing image for clicking the image for date picker pls help me to solve the issue.

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtDate").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

asp.net:

Comment: Is your `calendar.png` in the same folder as your aspx page? If no you should alter your `buttonImage` to something like `"/path/to/calendar.png"`

Comment: Together with the path to the image that must be the correct, the `txtDate` is the one that final rendered on the page ? or you need to use the `<%=txtDate.ClientID%>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a path to your image or include the image in the directory where your page is here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sH5Dq/) sample

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/2166/oxygen/48/kontact_date.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

**Edit :**

First of all see the source code if your textbox id changes, if so you got two option to either set it to ClientIDMode="static" or change the script to get the `ClientID` of textbox control:

```
$(function () {
        $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/2166/oxygen/48/kontact_date.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
```

Comment: i cant get that image in ascx

Comment: where is the image's location? Include that path.

Comment: buttonImage: "E:\usercontrol\usercontrol\img\calendar.png",

Comment: do either : buttonImage: "~/usercontrol/usercontrol/img/calendar.png" or buttonImage: "/img/calendar.png"

Comment: how can i use in this textbox  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> it is not working in this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the path of the `buttonImage`.

Make sure the path is correct means it should be in the **same directory** where the your `.aspx page` is.

Other wise change the path of the image.

Suppose that you page is in the `root directory` and images in the `image directory` the the path should be

```
buttonImage:"/image/to/calendar.png"
```

Also it could be the problem with the `ID` of you `text box` you can use `ClientId` as follows

```
 $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery for datePicker**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datefield").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: 'button', 
                buttonImage: "http://www.cphlibrary.org/images/events/calendar.jpg",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="datefield" />
```

## [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj9Xh/37/)

To make this Work you have to include Jquery 1.8.3 and [jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js)

Comment: @user3224577 you can upvote it and mark as answer if it helped. it helps to increase my reputation